# jQuery hidden span popup when clicking parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I have `<div>` element with a `<span>` element inside for course offerings.

When the user clicks the `<div>` element, it is supposed to open the corresponding child `<span>` element.

Then, ideally when the user clicks the next `<div>` element, it would close the previous child `<span>` element.

I can't even get the first child `<span>` element to open up.

Below, a snippet of my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $(".popup").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('span').toggle("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup"> English: Human Nature
  <span class="popuptext" id="English9">
        <h1>Human Nature</h1>
     <br>
       9th Grade ELA Course Description
   </span>
</div>
<div class="popup">English: Welcome to NY
  <span class="popuptext" id="EnglishELL">
        <h1>Welcome to NY</h1>
      <br>
      9th Grade ELA Course Description for ELLS
   </span>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you traveling up the DOM (`.closest('div')`)?

Comment: Why do you have a `</br>` when there's no `<br>`?

Comment: For the </br> that was just me being a noob. 

As for the (.closest('div')) I was giving it a try since just using $(this).find('span') wasn't working for me.

Comment: @RyanA. Gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var counter = 0;
    
    $(".popup").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('.popup').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.popuptext {
  display: none;
}
.popup.active > .popuptext {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup"> English: Human Nature
    <span class="popuptext" id="English9">
        <h1>Human Nature</h1>
       <br>
       9th Grade ELA Course Description
   </span>
</div> 
<div class="popup">English: Welcome to NY
    <span class="popuptext" id="EnglishELL">
        <h1>Welcome to NY</h1>
      <br>
       9th Grade ELA Course Description for ELLS
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Commenting your solution will do. What makes your version work? What did the OP did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[here my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/nuqgdvrs/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(".popup").click(function() {
    if($(this).find('span').hasClass('active')) {//This can be save in 2 variables {
      $(this).find('span').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('span').removeClass("active");
        $(this).find('span').toggleClass( "active" );
    }
  });
});
```

**Updated: without loops :)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  var active;
  $(".parent").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(!target) return;
    if($(active).hasClass('active')) {
      if(!$(target).find('span').hasClass('active')) {
        active.removeClass('active');
        active = $(target).find('span').addClass('active');
      } else {
          active = $(target).find('span').toggleClass('active')
      }
    } else {
        active = $(target).find('span').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] the answer and click on the `{}` button in the editor - It will allow you to create a working stack snippet, then you wouldn't have to trick the system using a fake code block (`:))))))))...`) You should also explain what you did to solve the problem. For more details please read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      var spans = $('.popup span').hide();
      $(".popup").click(function() {
        var this_span = $(this).find('span'),
        is_visible = this_span.is(":visible");
        spans.hide();
        if (!is_visible) {
            this_span.show();
        }
        });
    });
```